# Induction Question Is Completely Throwing Me Off

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x > -1$, $(1 + x) ^ n \geq 1 + nx$ for all $n \in \mathbb{ N
}$

I know the steps of induction, (base case, assume, prove), but the was this one is set up is completely different from any other problem I have seen. Having two variables in the same equation is what is confusing me, and I honestly have no idea where to even start with this.

Comment: Treat $n$ as the variable and $x$ as fixed.  And use `\in` instead of `E`.

Comment: So if I were to set up the base case, it would look like this: (1+x)^1 >= 1+1x ? I'm kind of confused on which part is the actual equation, and which part is just a rule...

Comment: This is Bernoulli's inequality, see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Comment: "Having two variables in the same equation": only one of them is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case $n=1$ is obvious,

Assume $n=k$ works, i.e. $(1+x)^k\geq 1+kx$, we want to prove $n=k+1$ also works

$(1+x)^{k+1}=(1+x)(1+x)^k\geq (1+x)(1+kx)$

Since $(1+x)(1+kx)=1+(k+1)x+kx^2\geq 1+(k+1)x$ (because $kx^2$ must be positive), so

$$(1+x)^{k+1}\geq 1+(k+1)x$$

Which is the inductive step we need to prove

Comment: I don't see where you're getting the base. Wouldnt you plug in 1 for n? Which would still leave you with x in the equation, so how did you end up with 1?

Comment: @jebus When you substitute $1$ for $n$ you get $1+x\ge 1+x$, which is obviously true

Comment: Okay. I forgot that it was greater than OR equal to. So to finish it would you factor out a 1+x for the second half of the equation first? Or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: @JebusCrust For case 1, you just need to verify that it is a true statement, regardless of the value of $x$. Since $1+x\geq 1+x$ is true (equality), so you can say it works for the case for $n=1$

Comment: Would you simply just divide both sides by (1+x) to get it to cancel, which would equal the original equation for k?

Comment: @JebusCrust You mean for case $n=k+1$? you would want to expand the bracket

Comment: Not exactly sure what that means?

Comment: @JebusCrust I have edited my answer, please refer to it